# Definir en que cuartil se encuentra valores de una columna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

A partir de una columna que contiene diferentes valores numéricos llamada 'col6' quiero saber para cada muestra en que cuartil se encuentra. Para representarlo quiero tener 4 columnas y hacerlo de manera binaria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que había pensado es crear 4 columnas una por cuartil e ir comprobando. Hice esto:

```
# Creo columnas y pongo todo a 0
df["Col6_Q1"] = 0
df["Col6_Q2"] = 0
df["Col6_Q3"] = 0
df["Col6_Q4"] = 0

# Calculo margenes
max = df["Col6"].max()
mitad = df["Col6"].max()/2
un_cuarto = df["Col6"].max()/4
tres_cuartos = df["Col6"].max()*3/4

# Compruebo en que cuartil se encuentra y pongo su columna a 1
if (df['Col6'] <= un_cuarto):
    df = df.assign(Col6_Q1 = 1)
```

Solo está el primer cuartil porque ya comprobé que este método no sirve.

Lo que pienso es que primero hay que crear una columna para categorizar en cuartiles y luego lo otro con `get_dummies()` se crean las 4 columnas binarias. Pero no se cómo hacerlo.

¡Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero, el cálculo de cuartiles no es tan simple como aplicar un coeficiente al máximo.

Por ejemplo, el cuartil mitad no es la mitad del máximo, sino aquél valor por debajo del cual estén la mitad de las observaciones (también llamado *mediana*). Para encontrar los valores de los cuartiles es necesario por tanto examinar la colección de datos entera y no sólo el máximo. Por suerte pandas tiene una función para eso `DataFrame.quantile()`.

Por ejemplo, voy a crear un DataFrame con unos cuantos números para ilustrarlo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"n": np.random.randint(1,100, 100)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

```
    n
0  54
1  20
2   6
3   8
4  55
```

Son números aleatorios entre 1 y 100. Con `df.n.max()` veo que su máximo es 99. Para obtener los cuartiles:

```
print(df.n.quantile([.25, .5, .75]))
```

```
0.25    30.00
0.50    54.00
0.75    80.25
Name: n, dtype: float64
```

Ves por cierto que el cuartil mitad (0.50) tiene valor `54.00` y no `49.5` como te saldría a ti usando la mitad del máximo.

Por otro lado ves que `quantile()` lo que devuelve es otro dataframe, del cual sólo nos interesan los valores (30, 54, 80.25), Éstos podemos capturarlos en una lista en la forma siguiente:

```
qs = df.n.quantile([.25, .50, .75]).values
```

Y ahora usamos esta lista para asignar las columnas extras que tú buscabas:

```
df["Q1"] = (df.n <=qs[0])+0
df["Q2"] = ((df.n <=qs[1]) & (df.n >qs[0])) +0
df["Q3"] = ((df.n <=qs[2]) & (df.n >qs[1])) +0
df["Q4"] = (df.n >qs[2]) +0
```

¿Qué significa? Tomemos la primera por ejemplo:

- `df["Q1"]=` creará una columna nueva llamada `"Q1"` la que asignará el resultado de la operación a la derecha del `=`, la cual se espera que sea una serie pandas (una columna).
- `(df.n <= qs[0])` es una operación vectorial, en la que compara cada elemento de la columna `df.n` con el valor del primer cuartil (era 30 como vimos). El resultado es `True` o `False`. Esta operación nos da entonces una columna de booleanos.
- `+ 0` es otra operación vectorial en la que se suma 0 a cada elemento de la columna obtenida en la anterior operación. Esto fuerza a tratar el `True` como `1` y el  `False` como `0`, produciendo así una columna de unos y ceros que es lo que querías.

El resto de asignaciones son similares y fáciles de interpretar.

El resultado sería este:

```
print(df.head())
```

```
    n  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
0  54   0   1   0   0
1  20   1   0   0   0
2   6   1   0   0   0
3   8   1   0   0   0
4  55   0   0   1   0
```